# Adding a corresponding date to max value

Tags: sql, oracle, date

The query that I have written below is giving me everything that I need except for the corresponding High_Water date. Basically what this query is doing is simple. Its giving me the MAX value throughout the life of the symbol however I'm not sure how to write in to the query so that the result set will show a 5th column with the corresponding date of the MAX value!

For example if a symbol X was entered in to the database on 01/01/2015 and it contains data up until today (11/06/2015). My current query will find the MAX AUM for symbol X and that max value was on 06/01/2015. I need my query to show me the 06/01/2015 date. Basically I need the query to find the MAX value and its corresponding date so that I know on what date the MAX AUM is reflected on.

```
SELECT
    A.SMBL,
    B.MLTPL,
    BEGINNING_DATE,
    ROUND(max(AUM/1000000.00)) AS HIGH_WATER_AUM      
FROM
    TBL1 A 
    JOIN TBL2 B ON A.SMBL = B.SMBL
WHERE
    A.SMBL IN = 'X' 
GROUP BY
    A.SMBL, B.MLTPL, BEGINNING_DATE
ORDER BY
    SMBL
```

Comment: what is `IN` -> `where A.SMBL IN = 'X' ` trying to create an alias why not just `=`? Why `order by SMBL` if all are `'X'` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the reason why it needs to be ordered because in my actual query I'm using more then one symbol. I used 'x' simply to ensure that the query doesn't appear crowded.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need KEEP FIRST/LAST:

```
select   a.smbl,
         b.mltpl,
         beginning_date,
         round(max(aum / 1000000.00)) as high_water_aum,
         max(high_water_date) keep (dense_rank first order by aum desc) hw_dt_of_max_row
from     tbl1 a 
         inner join tbl2 b on (a.smbl = b.smbl)
where    a.smbl = 'X'
group by a.smbl,
         b.mltpl,
         beginning_date
order by smbl;
```

The `keep (dense_rank first order by aum desc)` bit is doing the ordering and picking the row(s) with the highest aum. (You could rewrite this as `keep (dense_rank last order by aum)` if you wanted to.)

The `max(high_water_date)` is there in case there's more than one row that has the highest aum value - it simply picks the latest high_water_date to display. You could change that to `min(high_water_date)` if you so wished.

---

Here's a simple example illustrating the principle:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 20 val1 from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 10 val1 from dual union all
                     select 3 id, 40 val1 from dual union all
                     select 4 id, 100 val1 from dual union all
                     select 5 id, 70 val1 from dual union all
                     select 6 id, 100 val1 from dual union all
                     select 7 id, 80 val1 from dual union all
                     select 8 id, 70 val1 from dual union all
                     select 9 id, 90 val1 from dual)
select max(val1) max_val1,
       max(id) keep (dense_rank first order by val1 desc) max_val1_max_id1,
       max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by val1) max_val1_max_id2
from   sample_data;

  MAX_VAL1 MAX_VAL1_MAX_ID1 MAX_VAL1_MAX_ID2
---------- ---------------- ----------------
       100                6                6
```

Comment: I tried the query that you mentioned however the result set is coming up as an incorrect date. I know what the date should be and when I test it out on a specific symbol, the dates are way off.  Also I should have mentioned that the HIGH_WATER_DATE is an artificial name. Our symbols go by NAV_DATE and basically the high water aum will have a corresponding date that this max value happened on which is the NAV_DATE that I am aliasing as HIGH_WATER_DATE.

Comment: Perhaps if you updated your question with create table and insert statements of sample data, plus the output you're expecting to see, we'd stand a much better chance of working out how to help you. What exactly do you mean by "I got an empty result set"? I find it very strange that just adding a single column into the exact (well, apart from correcting the `a.smbl in = 'X'` syntax error) query you posted caused no rows to be returned.

Comment: My apologies for the miscommunication.  I realized that I needed to edit the symbol to the one that I'm actually using. However the result set was showing me incorrect data. I edited the original question. Hopefully that helps you guys understand exactly what I'm looking for! Please note that I already have the data that I need for some of the symbols that I'm testing. I just need the query to work properly in order for me to run it on other symbols.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a very simple demonstration of the KEEP FIRST/LAST function. Since you haven't provided any sample data for us to run your query on, it's impossible for us to say why you're seeing "incorrect" results. When I ask for sample data (both input and expected output), it's really not for the benefit of my own health, I promise you! It's so that we have a set of data that matches your conditions that we can work with ourselves, given that we're not sat next to you and can't see your screen etc.

Comment: If you still think the above query is returning incorrect results for your data, please provide sample data that reproduces your issue and explain what should be displayed (it doesn't have to be your exact data; you can obfuscate it etc. For preference, use subqueries to simulate the data in your tables in the same way I did in my test example). We'll stand a much better chance of being able to help you, that way *{:-)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a row_number to select the highest row.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
      SELECT A.SMBL, 
             B.MLTPL, 
             BEGINNING_DATE, 
             ROUND(AUM/1000000.00) AS HIGH_WATER_AUM,
             A.nav_date,      
             ROW_NUMBER() over 
                (PARTITION BY A.SMBL, B.MLTPL, BEGINNING_DATE ORDER BY AUM DESC) AS RN
      FROM TBL1 A 
      JOIN TBL2 B 
        ON A.SMBL = B.SMBL
      WHERE A.SMBL IN ('X','Y','Z')
    ) t
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY SMBL
```

Comment: Thanks guys, you guys were able to steer me in the right direction. I was able to get the query completed with the result set being exactly what I needed. I will post the answer to my query shortly

Comment: After reading your answer I update my answer. Please can you try it? Using row_number() is more efficient than calculating the max() and then perfom a look up with the table again.

Comment: I just ran the query that you wrote and unfortunately it does not give me the correct result set. I will post my result set compared to yours in a bit.

Comment: well, at least you can check the schema of how is done. Maybe next time you can include a sqlfiddle with data so we have something to work with. Like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18cc8/10

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one and good call on the sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that I was looking to write. I gives me the exact result set that I was looking for.

```
SELECT A.SMBL,
       B.MLTPL,
       BEGINNING_DATE,
       ROUND(MAX(c.AUM / 1000000.00)) AS HIGH_WATER_AUM,
       max(a.nav_date) AS HIGH_WATER_AUM
FROM TBL1 A
INNER JOIN TBL2 B
        ON A.SMBL = B.SMBL
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT SMBL,
                  max(AUM) AS AUM
           FROM TBL1
           GROUP BY symbol
           ) c
        ON A.SMBL = C.SMBL
       AND c.AUM = a.AUM
WHERE A.SMBL IN ('X','Y','Z')
GROUP BY A.SMBL,
         B.MLTPL,
         BEGINNING_DATE
ORDER BY SMBL
```

Answer (score 0):

@JuanCarlosOropeza. The result set that I was looking for is this

```
SMBL    MLTPL   BEGINNING_DATE       MAX(A.NAV_DATE)      HIGH_WATER_AUM
A        10    2008-12-01 00:00:00   2011-05-02 00:00:00         100
B        10    2011-10-04 00:00:00   2013-11-27 00:00:00         600
X        10    2008-11-24 00:00:00   2009-06-17 00:00:00         300
Y        10    2008-11-24 00:00:00   2015-03-26 00:00:00         500
Z        10    2008-12-01 00:00:00   2011-09-02 00:00:00         700
```

The result set that your query gave me was

```
SMBL     MLTPL  BEGINNING_DATE       MAX(A.NAV_DATE)       HIGH_WATER_AUM
A        10    2008-12-01 00:00:00   2015-10-15 00:00:00         100
B        10    2011-10-04 00:00:00   2015-10-15 00:00:00         600
X        10    2008-11-24 00:00:00   2015-10-15 00:00:00         300
Y        10    2008-11-24 00:00:00   2015-10-15 00:00:00         500
Z        10    2008-12-01 00:00:00   2015-10-15 00:00:00         700
```

You can see how its simply assigning a date to all of the different symbols even though their HIGHT_WATER_AUM in reality was on different dates.